# My drivers recognize my graphics card, but nvidia settings do not

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel, 16.10

I'm really sorry to be a bother with this, I'm having problems getting my graphics card to work properly on my computer.

#### PC Info:

- Custom PC Build
- Ubuntu 16.10
- Intel Skylake Processor - Asus Motherboard
- PNY GeForce 1060 3GB Graphics card
- Linux kernel 4.8.2-stable

#### What I did:

I've used Ubuntu-drivers to auto install the drivers for my graphics card, but after running Ubuntu-drivers `autoinstall` and rebooting my computer, I get a series of errors on screen.

```
[ 1847.764702] bbswitch: No suitable _DSM call found.
[ 1888.764702] bbswitch: No suitable _DSM call found.
[ 1888.764702] bbswitch: No suitable _DSM call found.
[ 1847.764702] bbswitch: No suitable _DSM call found.
[ 1888.764702] bbswitch: No suitable _DSM call found.
[ 1888.764702] bbswitch: No suitable _DSM call found.
```

Doing some reading I found that it may be due to having an outdated kernel so I updated from Ubuntu kernel 4.8.0 to Ubuntu kernel 4.8.2. That didn't seem to solve any of my issues.

My drivers menu seems to have the nvidia drivers recognized.

`lshw -C display` has my graphics card recognized and Ubuntu-drivers devices also can "see" my card.

However it seems nvidia-settings can't find my card information, and it definitely is not the thing rendering my graphics.

I think that because of the following.

```
$ glxinfo | egrep "OpenGL vendor| OpenGL renderer*"
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa DRI Intel (R) HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2)
```

#### The state of the problem now:

When I plug the HDMI cable into the graphics card there is no display output both before and after installing the drivers. The only display output I can get is when the HDMI cable is plugged into the motherboard.

It could be anything from my card not being plugged in or powered correctly to me needing to install other drivers and packages.

Check this album, for photos of the command line output of what I'm talking about : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgaDM.jpg

I would love ANY guidance on how to proceed as I've been tinkering with drivers and `apt install` all day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question was the the power cable on the graphics card wasn't plugged in.

It literally will turn on and recognize the device and install drivers, but if you don't plug in the power cable it will not work properly.