# bbswitch: No suitable _DSM call found

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda, bbswitch

I am trying to install CUDA on my Ubuntu 16.04, following [these instructions](https://medium.com/@acrosson/installing-nvidia-cuda-cudnn-tensorflow-and-keras-69bbf33dce8a).

One of the errors I've got so far is connected with necessity to "exit X" before installing the nvidia driver. So I press `Ctrl+Alt+F1`, log in, enter `sudo service lightdm stop` and receive the following error:

`bbswitch: No suitable _DSM call found`.

Any ideas about what is wrong and how I could fix it?

Comment: seems like a duplicate of:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/857816/my-drivers-recognize-my-graphics-card-but-nvidia-settings-do-not