# CUDA driver installation, error: `Unable to install the display driver, root access is needed.`

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, cuda

I try to install CUDA driver (more particularly GPU version of the Tensorflow) following [this instructions](https://medium.com/@acrosson/installing-nvidia-cuda-cudnn-tensorflow-and-keras-69bbf33dce8a). I haven't completed the Nvidia Driver installation, as I run into the [following error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914206/bbswitch-no-suitable-dsm-call-found), however `nvidia-smi` shows the corresponding GPU metrics, so I assume that the Nvidia driver is installed.

Now when I try to install the CUDA driver it fails with the following message:

```
Unable to install the display driver, root access is needed. Skipping any remaining installation actions.
```

The commands I enter are as per instructions:

```
sudo chmod +x cuda_7.5.18_linux.run
./cuda_7.5.18_linux.run --driver --silent
```

I've also tried a more up-to-date version of the CUDA driver, `cuda_8.0.61_375.26_linux.run`, but that doesn't seem to help, as the same error comes up.

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You misplaced `sudo`... Chmoding doesn't need root privileges, running the installer does.

Comment: Nice! I'll write an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that root access is needed therefore the installer must be run with `sudo`:

```
chmod +x cuda_7.5.18_linux.run
sudo ./cuda_7.5.18_linux.run --driver --silent
```