# Nvidia graphic driver is installed but the graphic card is not used!

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

It seems like the system has successfully installed the nvidia proprietary driver as shown in the below image

[image: driver installed]

However it seems like the system is not using the graphic card.

[image]

I am not sure what should I do from here. I followed almost every step required to use the graphic driver but it is still not using it.

[image]

BTW, there should be some way to configure to use graphic card on nvidia-x server settings but it is not showing up on my machine.

Also, the output of glxinfo clearly shows that my system is not utilizing the nvidia graphic card.

```
jaebum@jaebum-laptop:~$ glxinfo | grep renderer
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2)
```

Any help is welcomed :)

Note that my system is ubuntu 16.10.

(* it is a laptop so I am pretty sure I didn't make mistake like [My drivers recognize my graphics card, but nvidia settings do not](https://askubuntu.com/questions/857816/my-drivers-recognize-my-graphics-card-but-nvidia-settings-do-not) )

EDIT

I also added the result of the following command

```
jaebum@jaebum-laptop:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] HD Graphics 530
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_375_drm, nvidia_375
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 81)
```

EDIT2

output of the following command

```
root@jaebum-laptop:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu# dkms status
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.4.0-79-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.8.0-54-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: already did that :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: I just added the output of that command @Pilot6

Comment: The kernel module is not loading for some reason. What does `prime-select query` output? It is either a Secure Boot issue, or the driver is incorrectly installed.

Comment: prime-select query returns unknown. Hmm weird. I am sure that I turned off the secure boot. Should I try reinstalling driver then?

Comment: Run `sudo apt purge 'nvidia.*'` then `sudo apt install nvidia-375 nvidia-prime`.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have done that. Will check after reboot. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Did you notice any error messages?

Comment: No there was no error message.

Comment: I guess my laptop is doomed to not accept nvidia graphic card :(

Comment: So does it work now? If not post the output of `dkms status`.

Comment: root@jaebum-laptop:/home/jaebum# dkms status
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.4.0-79-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.8.0-54-generic, x86_64: installed

Comment: Please post it to your question. Is this the full output?

Comment: yeah that was full output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60052/discussion-between-jaebum-and-pilot6).

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you have a **Secure Boot** option enabled, and that feature is preventing nVidia's kernels from loading, thus Ubuntu will use the integrated card only.

Try *temporarily* disabling the Secure Boot feature, and test if the nVidia card is being utilized.

Disabling the **Secure Boot** should be possible via your UEFI BIOS (I access mine with **F2** when the system starts booting).

If that turns to be the case, you have to sign the nVidia driver, which is a saga in itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your lap-top has hybrid graphic. It switches to nvidia gpu when applications needs more video memory.

You need to install `bumblebee` to render graphic. F.e.
`optirun firefox >/dev/null 2>&1 &`.

Please check this resource:

[Bubmlebee for Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee)

[How to install nVidia drivers with Bumblebee on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549915/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-with-bumblebee-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Is there way to run every program solely on nvidia drivers, not using the stupid intel thingy?